# Issue with s3cmd accessing DigitalOcean Spaces storage service due to configuration file issue

Tags: s3cmd, digital-ocean-spaces

**TL;DR** If your use of `s3cmd` on Spaces from DigitalOcean says:

> Could not refresh role

Then try removing the cfg for it and starting again.

I was using the DigitalOcean Spaces and I somehow got my configuration of the API messed up when using the s3cmd. I couldn't figure out how to make the following error go away:

```
WARNING: Could not refresh role
ERROR: Test failed: 501 (NotImplemented): Server does not support one or more requested headers. Please see https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#aws-s3-compatibility
```

This was done when I was configuring the using the `s3cmd -c ~/cfg_file/location --configure` command.

I got there because when I used the command like `s3cmd -c ~/cfg_file/location la s3://somespace` I would get:

```
WARNING: Could not refresh role
WARNING: Could not refresh role
ERROR: S3 error: 501 (NotImplemented): Server does not support one or more requested headers. Please see https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#aws-s3-compatibility
```

So, after about 20 minutes of messing around with it, making new API keys, etc. I decided to just delete the cfg profile and start from scratch. That did the trick.

So, for others, I thought I would put this here so when they search, they will at least get an answer to the basic question, what should I do to move forward :)

Hope it helps.

**Epilogue**: I am sure someone will say that I didn't solve the "actual" issue and that this will pop-up again. They are right :) I just needed to move on and deleting the configuration file and starting with a new one was the fastest most "rational" way that I could think of always getting back to "known" state. So, if you do know more about "why" the `s3cmd` configuration file was messed up and how to fix it by modifying the file, please do tell. I just didn't have the time or energy to "read the code" :)